# TEX can't see figures on PDF

Tags: graphics

I am writing for an academic journal in LaTeX and I am using Texstudio. 
My problem is the journal format is using `\usepackage[dvips]{eps fig}` and to upload a figure this command being used is `\epsfxsize=08cm \epsfbox{fig_main.eps}`

So I am using texstudio and in the pdf format there is a box which contains the path of figure i.e., `fig_main.eps` but I can't see my actual figure.

So far I have tried using `epstopdf` with `graphic` and `\includegraphics{}` to upload figures (which I used in a conference paper and worked well) but I can't find the solution to see my figures on PDF.
I am a newbie in TeX and need urgent help.

Comment: haven't you got `draft` mode enabled somewhere? as a class option for example?

Comment: Draft option is enabled \documentclass[12pt,draft]{JCNtran}. In the Latex template, there is a PDF, the figures can be seen but when I run the tex version there, the figures again can't be seen in the new pdf.

Comment: `\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}` should never be used (and won't work with pdfltex teh `[dvips]` explictly over-rides the automatic detection and forces it to use code for latex/dvips rather than npdflatex. the epsfig package itself is only for emulating old (pre 1993) LaTeX 2.09 documents

Comment: @ahmet, what happens if you remove that option?

Comment: I have to use the draft version for the first submission. @David I remove \usepackage[dvips]{epsfig} but won't work

Comment: \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{main_fig1.eps}
\caption{Project }
\label{FIG:1}
\end{figure}

Comment: I'm not familiar with that class but usually passing the `draft` option is intended to do that. That is, part of what the option does is to replace figures with boxes with the name of the file. Are you sure that you are meant to see the images in the generated PDF and not to upload them separately as `.eps` files, for example? I've definitely seen journals which want images uploaded separately but I'm not sure how the process works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Draft mode is supposed to not show you the picture, but rather a box with the file name.  This is expected behavior, and won't change unless you take out the *draft* option.